# Efficient data interchange format using only C-style fprintf() statements?

Tags: python, binaryfiles, printf, dataformat, data-representation

I need to transfer the very large dataset (between 1-10 mil records, possibly much more) from a domain-specific language (whose sole output mechanism is a C-style `fprintf` statement) to Python.

Currently, I'm using the DSL's `fprintf` to write records to a flat file. The flat file looks like this:

```
x['a',1,2]=1.23456789012345e-01
x['a',1,3]=1.23456789012345e-01
x['a',1,4]=1.23456789012345e-01
y1=1.23456789012345e-01
y2=1.23456789012345e-01
z['a',1,2]=1.23456789012345e-01
z['a',1,3]=1.23456789012345e-01
z['a',1,4]=1.23456789012345e-01
```

As you can see the structure of each record is very simple (but the representation of the double-precision float as a 20-char string is grossly inefficient!):

```
<variable-length string> + "=" + <double-precision float>
```

I'm currently using Python to read each line and split it on the "=".

Is there anything I can do to make the representation more compact, so as to make it faster for Python to read? Is some sort of binary-encoding possible with `fprintf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err....
How many times per minute are you reading this data from Python?

Because in my system I could read such a file with 20 million records (~400MB) in well under a second.

Unless you are performing this in a limited hardware, I'd say you are worrying too much about nothing.

```
>>> timeit("all(b.read(20) for x in xrange(0, 20000000,20)  ) ", "b=open('data.dat')", number=1)
0.2856929302215576
>>> c = open("data.dat").read()
>>> len(c)
380000172
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I profiled my code with 20 million randomly generated records. It took 4.8 seconds to read, which is still quite acceptable. I guess the real bottleneck was the string split operation on every record (which I thought would benefit from a shorter string obtained through encoding), but after changing it from `line.split("=")` to `line.split("=", 1)`, I got an reasonable speed-up. So it seems that I don't really need to encode after all.

Answer (score 1):

A compact binary format for serializing float values is defined in the [basic encoding rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Encoding_Rules#BER_encoding) (BER). There they are called "reals".  There are implementations of BER for Python available, but also not too hard to write. There are libraries for C as well. You could use this format (that's what it was designed for), or a variant (CER, DER). One such Python implementation is [pyasn1](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/http://).

Comment: It turns out the bottleneck wasn't Python's read operation. However, I'd never heard of BER before, and it sounds like something I might use in the future. Your answer also gave me hints as to what to wiki ("data serialization", "asn.1", etc.). Now I know what to look for the next time I need a serialization format. Thanks very much!